# JPA syntax- UPDATE TABLE from another table

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to update some columns of a table from another one.

I would like to use JPA (JPQL) for creating the Query

I tried this syntax:

```
UPDATE 
    Table t1 JOIN Table t2 
    ON t1.x1 = t2.y1 AND t1.x2 = t2.y2 
SET t1.a1 = t2.a2 , 
    t1.b1 = t2.b2;
```

But I got an error about "The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar"

Is there a way to do this query using JPA(JPQL) syntax? with Native Query(MYSQL) it works fine.

Comment: Is the underlying database MySQL?

Comment: The guy is not present but `UPDATE...JOIN` is not supported in JPA. So, go with possible alternatives depending upon your functional / technical requirements. It should also be noted that this is a bulk update statement in which case, the persistence context is not synchronized with the result of such bulk statements. Manually clearing the first level cache is thus necessary. Thus, such statements should be issued in a separate transaction. Call  `EntityManager#refresh()` , obtain a new `EntityManager` or call `EntityManager.clear()` after the statement succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The following - however awful and inefficient - is equivalent and may be valid for JPQL:

```
UPDATE 
    Table t1 
SET t1.a1 = ( SELECT t2.a2
              FROM Table t2 
              WHERE t1.x1 = t2.y1 AND t1.x2 = t2.y2
            ), 
    t1.b1 = ( SELECT t2.b2
              FROM Table t2 
              WHERE t1.x1 = t2.y1 AND t1.x2 = t2.y2
            ) 
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Table t2 
        WHERE t1.x1 = t2.y1 AND t1.x2 = t2.y2 
      ) ;
```